# Dynamic width of div elements inside a fixed width div

Tags: css

I am dealing with a fixed width parent div that is being used in multiple pages. This div has many(3-5) child div elements inside it. For different pages, the number of child div elements vary, i.e. for page 1, the parent div has 3 child divs, for page 2, the parent div has 5 child divs etc.

How can I set the width  of these child elements so that they fully occupy the width of parent div in every page?

P.S. The constraint  is to not use SASS/Less and Bootstrap.

Comment: Post some code to play around!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sayrandhri/80r8wead/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are asking for a table where the width of every cell should be the same in proportion of the fixed width of the parent.

It is possible in CSS if you know the maximum possible number of children (if not you will always use all the space but the width of each cell will change based on the content)

When you know the maximum number if children, you add that property to the class `.height`: `max-width:Npx` where `N` is the `width` of the parent divided by the number of children

```css
.container {
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:500px;
    display:table;
}
.child{
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}

.child:last-of-type {
    border:none;
}
.height{
    min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container height">
    <div class="child height">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child height">Child 2</div>
    <div class="child height">Child 3</div>
    <div class="child height">Child 4</div>
    <div class="child height">Child 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know if display:table works on IE 9? You have any idea?

Comment: IE was the only thing that made me unsure of using table property! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `flex`

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work in older versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: unfortunately no, not before IE10

Comment: The end users are using older version IE also, please suggest something that is also cross browser compatible.

Comment: Then why not set it manually? For example, for 3 child `div`s, set their `width: 33.33%;` and for 4 child `div`s, set their `width: 25%;`

Comment: Ah sorry, you mentioned `dynamic`

Comment: I don't think there exists a pure CSS way to do this

Comment: do you know the max number possible of children?