# Equate height of all divs using just CSS

Tags: html, css

I have used display:table property, but the table-cells still wont be equal in height. Is there a way to make them equal without using JavaScript or jQuery? Internet Explorer compatibility has to be kept in mind.

```
<div class="envelope">
    <div class="fill col">
        ABC
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="fill ">DEF</div>
    <div class="fill col">
             XYZ
             <br><br><br>
             <br><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.envelope{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:table;
    width:300px;

}

.fill{
    background:#dddddd;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    padding:1%; 
    display:table-cell;
}

.col{
    background:#ff44ff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sayrandhri/yt18kLos/

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Comment: why did you use the float property? If you float it then you won't have the same height, if you put off the float, it will work

Comment: what version of IE should you support?

Comment: @francesco-es : in the fiddle it works, let me see if it works in the production environment. :)

Comment: btw after that I told you that, anyone answered using my hint

Comment: Indeed! How to mark a comment as the right answer? :p

Comment: I would recommend using `display:flex;` and `display:-ms-flexbox;` on the container element `.envelope` in your case, but this is only supported on IE10+, here is the full compatibility list for [display flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: @KarimAG, the flex property is not supported by IE9!

Comment: @Madhavi, , I posted my answer, and I put a motivation, not only the correction, we have to share knowledge, not only tips

Comment: @Francescoes. Nope, it is only supported on IE10+ ((with a prefix))

Comment: @KarimAG, our friend needs compatibility with IE9, otherwise `flex` would be a very good solution

Comment: @Madhavi, thanks for the correction of my english ; )

Comment: I know that's why I asked about the version he needs to support, it's a pity though because this CSS rule is one of the best rules out there, it should be better supported.

Comment: @KarimAG The end users are still using old versions. Something that still frustrates me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone answered but no one said why it is like that:

- When you use the `float` property the floated element are taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container.

The `float` could modify the computed value of the display values:

- In your case the `display: table-cell` becomes a `display: block`.
- So, yes the solution to have the same height if you don't want to set the `height` value (possible since it is computed as `display: block`) it to delete the `float:left`

Comment: Can you please look into this problem as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602011/dynamic-width-of-div-elements-inside-a-fixed-width-div

Answer (score 1):

update css like this

```
.fill{
   background:#dddddd;
   border-right:1px solid #000;
   width:30%;
   padding:1%;
   display:table-cell; 
}
```

I have removed the `float:left`

Answer (score 1):

Removing float: left will solve your problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/yt18kLos/1/

```
.envelope{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:table;
    width:300px;

}

.fill{
    background:#dddddd;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    /*float:left;*/
    width:30%;
    padding:1%; 
    display:table-cell;
}

.col{
    background:#ff44ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing `float:left;` will solve your problem

**CSS**

```
.fill{
  background:#dddddd;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  width:30%;
  padding:1%; 
  display:table-cell;
}
```